# Get request returning 404 error when called from android app

Tags: java, php, android

I'm working on creating an app and I'm pretty new to doing this. I'm using Android studio. I've created a php script and hosted it on my hostinger account, along with the database it's accessing. If I enter the URL for the script on my browser it gives me a warning saying that it needs a parameter (not sure if there is a way for me to enter a parameter when I test it like this?) and shows the array which I want returned (with all null values of course, since it doesn't have the parameter for the SELECT statement). When I try to call the php script from my code with the parameter it returns an "Error 404 - Page Not Found" error. This is where I store it to the string

```
RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Config.URL_GET_USER, username);
```

the URL it's referencing is definitely correct, as I can copy it straight from the code into the browser and it works. And I've printed the username string out on the line before to make sure it's correct and it is. Here's the relevant sections of code from the RequestHandler class

```
public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String username){
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL+username);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(s+"\n");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And finally here is the PHP script

```
<?php



$username = $_GET['username'];

 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username=$username";

 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $result = array();
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
 array_push($result,array(
 "user_id"=>$row['id'],
 "username"=>$row['username'],
 "password"=>$row['password'],
 "dob"=>$row['dob'],
 "forename"=>$row['forename'],
 "surname"=>$row['surname']
 ));

 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Let me know if you need any more information

EDIT: I've now added ?username= to the request so it's retrieving the array but the array is filled with null values. I think the error message I get when I try to access it through the browser is related to why this happens. It says:
"Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in" then it has the path to the php file and says line 12, so that's this line:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
```

Comment: What do the `requestURL` and `username` variable contain ? The final URL needs to look something like `http://www.example.com/phpFile.php?username=someone`, my guess is that you're missing the `?username=` part.

Comment: requestURL containts the URL of the php file, so using your example http://www.example.com/phpFile.php. The username variable only contains the username of the logged in user. So I guess from your example I would be missing the "?username=" part, so do I need to add that to the username string before I pass it in?

Comment: Yes, or, you can add it when the URL is created, eg: `URL url = new URL(requestURL+"?username="+username);`

Comment: Ok now it's getting an array back but it's filled with null values. I'll update the original thread with what I think is causing that to make it easier to see

Comment: That is probably because the username that you've searched for, doesn't exits in the database. You'll need to add a check in the php file, something like `if($r){....}` to make sure `$r` is not `null` (`0`).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the username is in the database, and it's already been checked with the login feature using a different php script which worked fine. Would it be any help if I included that script for you to look at?

Comment: I don't need to look at the other script, from the error message, it seems that `$r` is set to `0` because the SQL query doesn't return any results. I think that is because you haven't added quotes to the value in the `where` clause. Try to change your query to `"SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username=\"$username\""` the changed part here is `\"$username\"`

Comment: Ok now it works fine, thanks!